# umbraco page in mobile behavior

Tags: css, css-float

I have a simple ubraco site I have been building (http://mbicmsdev.azurewebsites.net/) but when it is rendered in mobile and the user strolls down, the pages can be slid out of view to the left or right.

Is there a style setting I can add to keep the div in frame?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set a responsive meta viewport tag within the `<head>` element of the HTML document:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

More info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: That seems to work,  originally I had
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> but in the iphone, I now have a 20px on the right hand side

Comment: Thank you, your fix was correct. An image was messing w/the right-hand side. Thanks